# NodeHandle::subscribe fail to subscribe topic

Tags: ros, subscribe, nodehandle, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm new to ROS and C++ and doing Programming for Robotics (http://www.rsl.ethz.ch/education-students/lectures/ros.html). My problem is "Create a subscriber to the /scan topic" in exercise2. Here is my code:

HuskyHighlevelController.Cpp File:

```
#include "husky_highlevel_controller/HuskyHighlevelController.hpp"
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h>

namespace husky_highlevel_controller {

HuskyHighlevelController::HuskyHighlevelController(ros::NodeHandle& nodeHandle) :
  nodeHandle_(nodeHandle)
{
  ros::Subscriber subscriber =
  nodeHandle_.subscribe("scan",1000,&HuskyHighlevelController::ScanCallback,this);
  ROS_INFO("Successfully launched node.");
}

HuskyHighlevelController::~HuskyHighlevelController()
{
}

void HuskyHighlevelController::ScanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan& msg)
{
ROS_INFO("Received");
}

}
```

husky_highlevel_controller_node.Cpp File:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include "husky_highlevel_controller/HuskyHighlevelController.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "husky_highlevel_controller");
  ros::NodeHandle nodeHandle("~");

  husky_highlevel_controller::HuskyHighlevelController huskyHighlevelController(nodeHandle);

  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

No problem with build but I launched husky_world.launch first then I ran this node (husky_highlevel_controller_node) and I checked the info of husky_highlevel_controller node and scan topic. Found No relationship between them (also rqt_console to check info message but receive nothing). I'm confused with

```
ros::Subscriber sub = handle.subscribe("my_topic", 1, &Foo::callback, &foo_object);
```

and

```
ros::Subscriber sub = handle.subscribe("my_topic", 1, callback);
```

From the ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c++), I think my_topic should be the topic found in rostopic list but didn't work for subscribing scan topic. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306743/nodehandle::subscribe-fail-to-subscribe-topic/) by [Xmice](https://answers.ros.org/users/38205/xmice/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As it's your homework: What is the scope of your subscriber and how long will it live?

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2018-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Xmice](https://answers.ros.org/users/38205/xmice/) on 2018-10-25**:
Thanks for the hint.

```
  ros::Subscriber subscriber =  nodeHandle_.subscribe("scan",1000,&HuskyHighlevelController::ScanCallback,this);
```

was the reason. I replace it by

```
subscriber_ =
nodeHandle_.subscribe("/scan",1000,&HuskyHighlevelController::ScanCallback,this);
```

Worked as expectedly.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-26**:
@Xmice: please mark the answer by @NEngelhard as correct by ticking the checkmark to the left of the answer. It will turn green.

**Comment by [Xmice](https://answers.ros.org/users/38205/xmice/) on 2018-10-26**:
@gvdhoorn: Done. I'll get familiar with the forum and thanks for the reminding.

**Comment by [dimitri](https://answers.ros.org/users/53755/dimitri/) on 2020-04-20**:
Thanks a lot I had the same problem and this solved it for me. I am not sure though what exactly is the difference between the two versions. Why is the scope different?